# What are the Electric and Magnetic Properties of Aluminum Oxynitride?

Tags: electromagnetism, material-science

Is Transparent Aluminum ([Aluminum Oxynitride](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_oxynitride)) a good conductor of electricity? Also, is it attracted by a magnet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No and No.

There are very few transparent electricity conductors (like ITO), and this is not one of them.

Also, I don't see it in a list of common ferromagnetic materials (if that's what you was asking by 'attracted').